# Solve a trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following trigonometric inequality:

$$\cos(x+\frac 2 3 \pi)+2\cos{x}\geq 0 \rightarrow\cos{x}\cos({\frac 2 3 \pi)}-\sin{x}\sin({\frac 2 3 \pi})+2\cos{x}\geq0\rightarrow$$
$$3\cos{x}-\sqrt 3\sin{x}\geq 0$$

I could either put the inequality into a system, like this:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
3\cos{x}-\sqrt 3\sin{x}\geq 0 \\ 
\sin^2x+\cos^2{x}=1\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

or divide both sides of the inequality by $\cos{x}$. What would I have to do in the latter case?

Something like this?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
\cos{x} > 0 \\ 
\tan{x}\leq\sqrt3\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

and

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
\cos{x} < 0 \\ 
\tan{x}\leq\sqrt3\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

How does the system approach work? How would I get the solutions by doing that? Any hints?

Comment: Use $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. I used it, didn't I? Please look at the first few lines of the question.

Comment: I mean, use it once again.

Comment: Note that $\cos x$ can be $0$.

Comment: @mathlove Great point, thanks. So basically the second approach (putting the equation in a system and evaluating the value of $\cos{x}$ is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$3 \cos x-\sqrt3 \sin x \ge 0$$
$$\sqrt3 \cos x- \sin x \ge 0$$
$$\frac{\sqrt3}2 \cos x- \frac 12\sin x \ge 0$$
$$\sin \frac{\pi}{3} \cos x- \cos \frac{\pi}{3}\sin x \ge 0$$
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)\ge 0$$